# Аттач файлов до создания объекта

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Имеем простейшее приложение Blog. Создание записи, просмотр записи.

Также есть возможность сделать аттач картинок к записи. Реализовано это через модель `Attachment` и связь `has_many`.

Захотелось немного улучшить приложение и сделать закачку картинок сразу после их выбора, а не как раньше после создания поста.

Тут возникла сложность, объекты `Attachment` создаются перед созданием объекта `Blog`. Тогда как установить связь между записью и загруженными картинками? Как `attachment`'у прописать `blog_ig`. И как быть если картинки были выбраны, а создавать блог передумали и закрыли страницу

Comment: Делать сохранение блога перед вставкой картинок

Comment: не хочется делать создание записи в блоге в два шага: сначала текст, потом заливка картинок.

Comment: Вы не поняли я намекал но создание транзакции. Алгоритм приблизительно следующий, начинается транзакция: создаете запись в бд получаете *BlogId*, при желании  прикрепляете изображения, сохраняете в бд с привязкой к конкретному блогу, в случае если пользователь сохранил статью, делаете комит транзакции, иначе удаляете изображения если они были сохранены. как то так

Comment: теперь понятно! супер, буду пробовать спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Требуется создать пустой ресурс для аттачмента :

```
@attachment = @post.attachments.build
```

В случае нескольких аттачментов все зависит от того, сколько картинок, можно несколько раз вызывать `build`.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы.

Answer (score 0):

Если вам необходима закачка картинок и сразу их отображение на странице создания опроса, я думаю здесь вполне подойдет ajax.

Comment: спасибо, но вопрос был не в этом )